# Burning Audio CD for stereo CD player

Tags: cd

I'd like to burn MP3 files to an audio CD. I tried K3b, but it just burns WAV files to the CD-ROM. As far as I know, a regular stereo CD player will only play cda format.

The end result files must play on a regular stereo CD player. Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used k3b in ages.. but if you select audio CD and then added your mp3 files, it should work just fine on a CD player.

CD audio is encoded in PCM format and specifically 16bit and 44.1Khz sample rate.
WAV also uses PCM.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Audio_CDs

Basically.. are you sure that it's burning the WAV files as a data cd.. and not just using the WAV files as a container for the PCM audio before it burns it to the CD?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it's just using the WAV files as a container - here's what the audio CD looks like in Nautilus: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GzchV.png"> - unfortunately I don't own a regular CD player, so I have no way to test it. The person I'm sending it to lives in another country, which is why I'd like to be as sure as I can before I send it out.

Comment: I've never used an audio cd with nautlis, but the fact that it says "These files are on an audio cd" is a dead give away that it's burned correctly. If you want confirmation.. try to rip it... You can't rip a data disk! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CDRipping

Comment: Note: it wouldn't be unusual for a file browser to pretend the CD has wav files for convenience.

Comment: Hmm. I tried a commercial audio CD, and Rhythmbox popped right up and started playing the songs. If I try to play the one I burned with k3b, Rhythmbox says it can't play that format. Which is why I'm guessing it's not a proper audio cd. Any ideas? I appreciate the help.